# 18.04: Sound crackling - pulseaudio CPU usage jumps

Tags: pulseaudio, performance, cpu

I noticed that when I do some action, sound starts crackling and mouse  starts freezing for a short amount of time (like 1 sec).

This happens, for example, when I scroll page on browser (not just Chrome) or when I start some program, sometimes when I type on keyboard.

Everytime this happens, CPU usage of

`/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog`

jumps to 30% - 60% for a moment (like 1 sec).

Do you know what to do to fix this?

**EDIT**

```
milano@milano-PC:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dev/ice 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**END OF SYSLOG**

I noticed freezing and crackling at 19:36:50 but there is nothing logged in syslog.

```
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ GW2470 (DFP-1): connected
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ GW2470 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ GW2470 (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ GW2470 (DFP-2): connected
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ GW2470 (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ GW2470 (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jan 19 19:09:18 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MST TV MONITOR (DFP-6): connected
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MST TV MONITOR (DFP-6): Internal TMDS
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MST TV MONITOR (DFP-6): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2622]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC gnome-shell[2758]: Object St.Icon (0x559e65230cf0), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it.
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC gnome-shell[2758]: Object St.BoxLayout (0x559e6522fe30), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it.
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: == Stack trace for context 0x559e64485340 ==
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #0 0x7fffc77043c0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/osdWindow.js:206 (0x7f0fb26c7780 @ 231)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #1 0x7fffc7704ae0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #2 0x7fffc7704ba0 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f0fb29f12b8 @ 367)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #3 0x7fffc7704c90 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f0fb29d2230 @ 386)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #4 0x559e6491d620 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js:531 (0x7f0fb26042b8 @ 127)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #5 0x7fffc77058e0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #6 0x7fffc77059a0 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f0fb29f12b8 @ 367)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: == Stack trace for context 0x559e64485340 ==
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #0 0x7fffc77043c0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/osdWindow.js:207 (0x7f0fb26c7780 @ 273)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #1 0x7fffc7704ae0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #2 0x7fffc7704ba0 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f0fb29f12b8 @ 367)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #3 0x7fffc7704c90 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f0fb29d2230 @ 386)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #4 0x559e6491d620 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js:531 (0x7f0fb26042b8 @ 127)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #5 0x7fffc77058e0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #6 0x7fffc77059a0 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f0fb29f12b8 @ 367)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC gnome-shell[2758]: Object St.Icon (0x559e65230cf0), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it.
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC gnome-shell[2758]: Object St.BoxLayout (0x559e6522fe30), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it.
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: == Stack trace for context 0x559e64485340 ==
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #0 0x7fffc7704a80 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/osdWindow.js:206 (0x7f0fb26c7780 @ 231)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #1 0x7fffc7704ae0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #2 0x7fffc7704ba0 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f0fb29f12b8 @ 367)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #3 0x7fffc7704c90 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f0fb29d2230 @ 386)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #4 0x559e6491d620 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js:531 (0x7f0fb26042b8 @ 127)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #5 0x7fffc77058e0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #6 0x7fffc77059a0 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f0fb29f12b8 @ 367)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: == Stack trace for context 0x559e64485340 ==
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #0 0x7fffc7704a80 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/osdWindow.js:207 (0x7f0fb26c7780 @ 273)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #1 0x7fffc7704ae0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #2 0x7fffc7704ba0 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f0fb29f12b8 @ 367)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #3 0x7fffc7704c90 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f0fb29d2230 @ 386)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #4 0x559e6491d620 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js:531 (0x7f0fb26042b8 @ 127)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #5 0x7fffc77058e0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:09:19 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #6 0x7fffc77059a0 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f0fb29f12b8 @ 367)
Jan 19 19:11:43 milano-PC brave_brave.desktop[24449]: [24449:24449:0119/191143.540386:ERROR:media_internals.cc(114)] Cannot get RenderProcessHost
Jan 19 19:15:01 milano-PC CRON[26668]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jan 19 19:16:48 milano-PC systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Jan 19 19:16:48 milano-PC systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Jan 19 19:17:01 milano-PC CRON[26944]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 19 19:21:39 milano-PC dhclient[2141]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.241 on eno1 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x44ec198c)
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC dhclient[2141]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.241 from 192.168.0.1
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1547922100.1711] dhcp4 (eno1):   address 192.168.0.241
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1547922100.1711] dhcp4 (eno1):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1547922100.1711] dhcp4 (eno1):   gateway 192.168.0.1
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1547922100.1712] dhcp4 (eno1):   lease time 3600
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1547922100.1712] dhcp4 (eno1):   hostname 'milano-PC'
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1547922100.1712] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserver '213.46.172.37'
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1547922100.1712] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserver '213.46.172.36'
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1547922100.1712] dhcp4 (eno1):   domain name 'home'
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1547922100.1712] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed bound -> bound
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC dbus-daemon[996]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=1024 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC dhclient[2141]: bound to 192.168.0.241 -- renewal in 1593 seconds.
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC dbus-daemon[996]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [eno1]: new request (1 scripts)
Jan 19 19:21:40 milano-PC nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [eno1]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan 19 19:23:19 milano-PC google-chrome.desktop[3804]: [1:84:0119/192319.584997:ERROR:rtpreceiver.cc(116)] AudioRtpReceiver::OnSetVolume: No audio channel exists.
Jan 19 19:25:01 milano-PC CRON[27798]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jan 19 19:26:02 milano-PC kernel: [14904.225903] perf: interrupt took too long (2532 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 78750
Jan 19 19:27:25 milano-PC dbus-daemon[996]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.317' (uid=1000 pid=27949 comm="/snap/slack/11/usr/lib/slack/slack --executed-from" label="snap.slack.slack (complain)")
Jan 19 19:27:27 milano-PC gnome-shell[2758]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.3403/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/Slack1
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC gnome-shell[2758]: Object .Gjs_AppIndicatorIconActor__1 (0x559e67ded840), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it.
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: == Stack trace for context 0x559e64485340 ==
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #0 0x7fffc7703370 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:83 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 87)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #1 0x559e6491d7f0 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/indicatorStatusIcon.js:93 (0x7f0fb00c6780 @ 58)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #2 0x7fffc7703f50 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #3 0x7fffc7704010 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f0fb29f12b8 @ 367)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #4 0x7fffc77040b0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f0fb29d2230 @ 386)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #5 0x559e6491d768 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/appIndicator.js:190 (0x7f0fb00b4450 @ 22)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #6 0x7fffc7704c90 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #7 0x559e6491d6c0 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:176 (0x7f0fb00b36f8 @ 26)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #8 0x7fffc7705870 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #9 0x559e6491d620 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:170 (0x7f0fb00b3670 @ 68)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #10 0x7fffc7706460 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f0fb29b5de0 @ 71)
Jan 19 19:27:38 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: #11 0x7fffc7706530 b   self-hosted:918 (0x7f0fb29f12b8 @ 394)
Jan 19 19:33:31 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x5000084 (*syslog (/)
Jan 19 19:34:14 milano-PC kernel: [15396.473952] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=70:85:c2:7c:b8:ff:6c:fd:b9:bc:0e:1b:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.186 DST=192.168.0.241 LEN=324 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=40386 LEN=304 
Jan 19 19:34:14 milano-PC kernel: [15396.632839] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=70:85:c2:7c:b8:ff:6c:fd:b9:bc:0e:1b:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.186 DST=192.168.0.241 LEN=324 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=40386 LEN=304 
Jan 19 19:34:15 milano-PC kernel: [15397.799923] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=70:85:c2:7c:b8:ff:6c:fd:b9:bc:0e:1b:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.186 DST=192.168.0.241 LEN=324 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=40386 LEN=304 
Jan 19 19:34:16 milano-PC kernel: [15398.959841] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=70:85:c2:7c:b8:ff:6c:fd:b9:bc:0e:1b:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.186 DST=192.168.0.241 LEN=324 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=40386 LEN=304 
Jan 19 19:35:01 milano-PC CRON[28933]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jan 19 19:37:46 milano-PC org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2758]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x5000084 (tail (~/) )
```

Comment: I'd try to diagnose the problem before attempting to fix it. For example, the syslog might have some info, also, the output of `aplay -l` seems relevant. I am not sure the hardware specs you've highlighted are relevant though.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thank you Mike. I've added output of aplay -l and tail of syslog to the end of the question. I've noticed crackling at 19:36:50 but there is nothing in syslog with that or close to that time.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on Debian 9. When playing music and some action claims for CPU usage, audio jump-cracks happens for 1-2 seconds.

Finally I think got the 'solution':

By default pulseaudio 'nice' process is -11; so: "Why don't let all the pulse-related processes in nice 0 and prio 20?

So, that is what I done:

```
$ sudo editor /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

high-priority = no
nice-level = 0
realtime-scheduling = no
realtime-priority = 20
```

Save (on `vi` :x/:wq) the file and do 'pulseaudio -k' or restart.

It's not perfect solution, but has improved 85% the audio playback; no more audio jumps/cracks when open chrome.

I am also using [PulseEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects).

Comment: the settings are: 'yes -11 yes 5' respectively by default.